# Place an activity with its layout on the Main Activity on launch

Tags: java, android

**Objective: Modular approach**

I am trying to understand an approach where the Main Activity sort of acts like a stage where I stack sub components on top of it having some sort of modular approach.

**MainActivity.java** *(Parent)*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

**UserList.java** *(child)*

```
public class UserList extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);
    }

    public void initView(ArrayList<UserVO> users) {
        this.users = users;
        userList.setAdapter(new UserListAdapter());
    }

    class UserListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return users.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list, null);

            TextView givenName = view.findViewById(R.id.givenName);
            givenName.setText(users.get(i).givenName());
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_user_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.components.UserList">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userList"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="715dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I believe `ListView` requires this somewhere, each cell has a textField

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/givenName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

**Question**

How can I add `UserList` on app launch to the MainActivity?

**Edit**

I've followed the same naming convention. Here is an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

[image]

Comment: You want to inflate the listview in the mainactivity?

Comment: Have you read about [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)s?

Comment: yes, while isolating `listView` related code in a separate `UserList` class.

Comment: You can't combine separate Activities. If you want `MainActivity` to be host to several different components, then make `UserList` and whichever others into `Fragment`s that can be transacted into and out of `MainActivity`.

Comment: @deHaar Want to keep it simple, Fragments is advanced for me at the moment. or if there's no simple solution then can I've a minimalistic example using my code?

Comment: you should not try to add one activity to another, they are not designed for that. You can use custom views, or fragments to achieve what you want.

Comment: As said by @VladyslavMatviienko you should not add activities to one another. And Fragments are not at all the advanced concept to anyone. Fragments are the part of the Activity. You can achieve your solution easily using the fragments.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I've followed tutorials but cant wrap my head around it, if I can see my code in a fragment example, I'd understand well.

Comment: Try some more simple things with fragments. See some tutorials about them first.

Comment: I've provided all the building blocks in my code, appreciate if someone can mold it into a fragment way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using fragments,

```
Activity Main code,

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadData();
}

private void loadData() {

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_layout,new ListViewFragment())
            .commit();

}
}
```

activity_main layout:(need to use frame layout to implement fragments)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"/>
```

Here comes the fragment code:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

private String listItems[] = {"vfvd","vdvvfv","vvddv","vfddvvd"}; //static data
ListView userList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view, container, false);



    userList = view.findViewById(R.id.userList);

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new 
    ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.user_list_items,listItems);
    userList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    return view;

}
```

}

And fragment layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ListViewFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/userList"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="715dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```

code for textview where we need to put the listview data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/givenName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:text="TextView"
android:textSize="18sp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

You have to implement the adapter code in the fragment I just used the static data and I was able to get the feature you wanted. If you need further help I can do it for you comment below. Thank you.

Comment: sure @Developer.I have added the static data do it with your code.If its the answer you asked for then please accept my answer

Comment: I've having an issue `Android resource compilation failed error: no element found`. for `tools:context=".ListViewFragment">`. My ListViewFragment is inside a package, does that matter?

Comment: Oh I have named my fragment as ListViewFragment..You need to put your fragment name in the tools else you can remove that line @Developer

Comment: I've followed the same naming convention, please see the screenshot in my question under Edit

Comment: You need to put that as .components.ListViewFragment. @Developer.You have to mention that parent folder.

Comment: We are getting closer, I gave the full package path and it worked, I think I'm missing one last thing `ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView`. What part of my code should I show you in a screenshot? Code is compiling fine, it's runtime error

Comment: you need to create the listview component like a text view. I have put the code called "code for text view where we need to put the listview data" below is that code.put the textview id and use that id in the adapter where you are setting the text @Developer

Comment: I'm afraid this is not helping me, I've put all 5 pieces of code in a screenshot in my edit, please see if you can spot something there.

Comment: click on this discussion chat.I can solve your problem